# Search for Values in PivotTable and Copy into Different Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a tool to track project labor costs across multiple sites at our company. I ran into an issue implementing this as not all projects are worked on each month. As such I have had to modify to the tool to account for all projects each month regardless of if they were worked on.

I need to search for 17 individual strings in a PivotTable and if the string is found copy all cells below that string into another tab which calculates the cost. This find and copy function is where I am stuck.

I created some code that copied the data that was specific to a location of the string, but it did not account for the fact the project title (string) will be in the same place in this table each month when this is run. The position of where this data will be copied however does not change.

Appreciate any guidance to get me started...

Comment: I am using this to find the string                                                                                With Sheets("PivotTable")
Cells.Find(What:="TRM-0000", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate                                          What I need to do next is copy all cells below the location of the string ("TRM-0000") into the "Cost Calc" tab starting at cell B5

Comment: I have used the code below and the offset is working, but it only copies the one cell below the location of TRM-0000. I need it to copy from the 1 offset cell through row 397Sub TRM0000()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim f As Range
Dim g As Range
Dim Calc As Range

Set Ws = Sheets("PivotTable")

Set f = Ws.Range("C3:Z3").Find(What:="TRM-0000", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set g = f.Offset(1, 0)
Set Calc = g

Calc.Copy
Sheets("Cost Calc").Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlValues

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I am basing this off of the code that you posted in your comment. I found the desired range using:

1. **First Row** of the data below the header (assumed to be row 4)
2. **Last Row** of data (calculated by finding the largest row that has a cell with data)
3. **Column** of the project title match

```
Sub TRM0000()
```

`Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim firstRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim column As Long
Dim Calc As Range

Set Ws = Sheets("PivotTable")

firstRow = 4
lastRow = Ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
column = Ws.Range("C3:Z3").Find(What:="TRM-0000", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).column

Set Calc = Ws.Range(Ws.Cells(firstRow, column), Ws.Cells(lastRow, column))

Calc.Copy
Sheets("Cost Calc").Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlValues

End Sub`

This should be a solution for this specific project title. However, you said you have 17! Instead of recreating this code for each, I would recommend storing the 17 project titles (could be in a tab of the workbook or enumerated in the VBA code), creating a for loop to run through that list, and making the project title and output range references dynamic in the VBA code.

Comment: Extremely helpful and I was able to generate a version of the file that works for now. Would however like to explore a For loop to draw from a separate tab of active projects, but am having trouble understanding how to structure the loop. I have outlined what I want to do but not sure how to execute. General process is below. Any guidance on how to get started is appreciated. 1) Read projects list from Active Projects tab 2) Search for each project found in Pivot Table tab 3) Copy into Cost Calc Tab. I assume I will be able to use the same code to copy the info with a new dynamic variable thx